# Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query error for "read:org" on GitHub

Tags: github, graphql, token

I am using GraphQL to query GitHub but getting this error:

`The 'name' field requires one of the following scopes: ['read:org'], but your token has only been granted the: ['repo'] scopes. Please modify your token's scopes at: https://github.com/settings/tokens.`

Answer (score 0):

### Generate and use a key that has sufficient access

- **Step 1**
  In github, select the scopes you need
- **Step 2**
  Generate the new token
- **Step 3**
  Use that token in your app (strongly preferred through an env variable).
- **Step 4** Restart app may be necessary.

See screenshots below.  My full key is obviously not shown.

The github navigation is a little tricky, it is currently:

**A** Click on "Developer settings"

[image]

**B** Click on "personal access tokens"

[image]

**C** Click on 'generate token"

[image]

### Token Settings:

[image]

[image]